# MySql - build a view from 2 table with some calculations

Tags: mysql, view, max, case

I try to put together i bookingsystem and this part is left to understand. Can this be done with a CASE statement or how should i think?

I am a beginner and like short/easy code.

How do i get it from here...

**date_source_table**

```
---id---+-----date------+---times---+---
   1       2020-01-02         3
   2       2020-01-03         2
   3       2020-01-04         3
```

**time_source_table**

```
 ---id---+----time------
       1       09:00
       2       09:30
       3       10:00
```

**date_time_result_view**

```
---id---+-----date------+---time---+---
   1       2020-01-02       09:00
   2       2020-01-02       09:30
   3       2020-01-02       10:00
   4       2020-01-03       09:00
   5       2020-01-03       09:30
   6       2020-01-04       09:00
   7       2020-01-04       09:30
   8       2020-01-04       10:00
```

Best regards
/Svante

Comment: Except for the `id` column, your result is a `CROSS JOIN` between the two tables.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. Did you realise that the date_source_table contains amount of timslots from time_source_table? It has to be CROSS JOIN with a twist? The first date pick 3 timeslots from the other table and so on...

Comment: Oh, that's a little tricker. You can probably do it using window functions, but I'm not very familiar with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL 8+ You can use the `row_number()` window function to number the records in `time_source_table`. You can then join them to `date_source_table` on these numbers being less than or equal to `date_source_table.times`. You can also use `row_number()` to get the "IDs" for the output, if theses should in fact be just numbers from 1 to *n*.

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY dso.date,
                                   tso.time) id,
       dso.date,
       tso.time
       FROM date_source_table dso
            INNER JOIN (SELECT tsi.time,
                               row_number() OVER (ORDER BY tsi.time) rn
                               FROM time_source_table tsi) tso
                       ON tso.rn <= dso.times;
```

If `time_source_table.id` is guaranteed to be in order of `time` and has no gaps you can also use that to join on. But if that column is just an `AUTO_INCREMENT` these guarantees aren't given. That may produce unwanted results all of a sudden. So use that with great care, if you must.

Comment: Thank you sticki bit

Now i have some work too learn the code and understand how it works...
There are 3 varnings but it works like a charm. :-)

`SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY dso.date,
X                                   tso.time) id,
X       dso.date,
X       tso.time`